# CoCart - Where Can I find or make a new Cart Key?

Tags: javascript, api, rest, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to make an app using Woocommerce and CoCart. CoCart is used for the cart items. It works fine when I am trying to add update and delete with JWT. But what to do with guest users?

So I read that you can use a cart_key in the params. However, do I need to make my own cart_key like: '12345' or even better use a random character and number generator?

Or does CoCart gives you a cart_key when you put in a first item in the card and you call the endpoint without a JWT? (I tried this but if I do not put a cart_key without JWT I get an error message.

Do you have any experience?
Thanks!

Comment: https://docs.cocart.xyz/?javascript--node#cart-key-what-is-a-cart-key

Comment: I read that page but to be honest, I do not get what it says :(.. It is saying: IF you want to create your own". So there must be a way to auto generate it but I don't know where

Comment: @Justinas Could you maybe explain it to me in easier words?

Comment: `setCookie('wp_cocart_session_' . COOKIEHASH, md5(time()))`

Comment: setCookie is not a function. I use flutter and there is no package available. I cannot find a good explanation on the internet... Very strange...

Comment: It's PHP command, not front-end, and since you are using WP, you are using PHP

Comment: Hmm okay. How should I sync the command with my front-end application when a new item is added to the cart?