# Safe to call WooCommerce, WordPress and CoCart endpoints in frontend? I need your opinion

Tags: javascript, php, flutter, security, woocommerce

#### Question

I got a question about **security**. I am building a **mobile webshop** in **Flutter**. Is it bad to make those API calls in the **frontend**? Should I make a separate **backend** for it in **Node** for example?

I have also read that you can 'create' your own endpoints in WordPress with **PHP**. What about that? Does that make it any safer or not?

#### What endpoints do I use?

There is an existing **WooCommerce API** to retrieve products, get categories, and create orders on the WooCommerce API. On the **CoCart API**, you can retrieve the cart, add to the cart, delete the cart, etc...

For the **Mollie payment APIs**, I think it is better to make a backend.

#### My take on it

I think it is fine to call those endpoints in the front end. I have seen Flutter packages for WooCommerce to call those endpoints.  Yes, I do send the basic auth in the headers... so I am not sure how 'dangerous' that is.

But on the other side. What can the 'hacker' do? They can see all the products, that is fine I guess. I am not sure if they can create orders... They cannot steal money at least :)

#### Reference code

For reference, here is a piece of code when calling an endpoint:

```dart
Future<Product> getProductById(int productId) async {
    String basicAuth =
        'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));
    print(basicAuth);

    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.parse(
            'https://websitename/wp-json/wc/v3/products/${productId}'),
        headers: <String, String>{'Authorization': basicAuth});
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return Product.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed');
    }
  }
```

##### Let me know your opinion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When talking about security main question is what goes over the network request. If your username & password from code above is something to keep secret, that can't be on client side.

If you sent code to user, user got it and can check what's happening while tracing network requests.

You can always skip the UI, debug network request and take all the details that were sent over that request and send those requests with cURL or anything else. Yet client must authenticate somehow, and that's a wide topic from "unlisted" URLs where you just need to have exact "random id" to get to the resource (e.g. youtube's or many file sharing services use that as "unlisted" link, which means this won't be in search results but if you have exact link, you will get into the resource) to oAuth2, which you can learn more about [here](https://oauth.net/2/) and
you could check this post too which covers several methods of [token-based authentication](https://www.pingidentity.com/en/resources/blog/posts/2021/ultimate-guide-token-based-authentication.html).

Comment: The username and password will be sent over the network request no matter what right. If I send it to my own backend or send it to the wooCommerce backend directly, the username and password are still 'visible'. 

Is oath2 the same as a JWT?

Comment: oath2 may use JWT but it's full authentication handshake protocol too. JWT is the way to build a token basically.

Comment: you should not use user/psw to authenticate each request, while if any request is "leaked" your user's credentials are leaked too. Better get temporary access token and use that instead. If token is leaked, you could have security to not use token e.g. on different IP then it was created etc. and invalidate token if anything bad detected. In user/psw case you would need ask user to reset password.

Comment: Hmm okay, Yeah, so after the user logged in once, you get a token, and with that token you can execute requests.  Aha that is a good idea, to check the IP. But how about the basic auth token I get from the WooCommerce plugin in the beginning?

I got a WooCommerceUsername and wooCommercePassword as shown here: https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-rest-api/ (3rd picture)

I use the basic auth to get all products. Because users can see products without being logged in. But doing that request, the user has 'access' to the 'keys'. How can I secure that part?

Comment: if you depend on 3rd party code and that code sends user credentials on each request, you can ask 3rd party to make it more secure or drop 3rd party code. If my responses helped, please consider upvoting :)

Comment: Do you have any experience with CoCart? Could you maybe check out this question then? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71484353/cocart-where-can-i-find-or-make-a-new-cart-key